# Formula for the power of a 2-by-2 block matrix

Tags: matrices, reference-request, block-matrices

**EDIT**: the original formula was not valid for block matrices. The formula below is now correct.

> **Exercise:** If
> $$ M =
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     A & 0 \\
>     B & C
> \end{bmatrix} \in \mathsf{M}_n(\mathbb{C}),$$
> then
> $$ M^p =
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     A^p                                   & 0     \\
>     \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} C^k B A^{p - 1 - k}  & C^p
> \end{bmatrix}, \forall p \in \mathbb{N}. $$

I've seen this formula dozens of times over the years (there is also an upper-triangular version), but I can't seem to place a reference for it.

Any references would be greatly appreciated (I am only looking for a reference, I realize that it follows from induction and the definition of matrix multiplication).

Comment: No—I would like a reference from a paper or textbook.